# Laravel 4 Auth works but does not stay logged in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In my Laravel 4 App I use the Auth functionality.

I submit my login form to:

```
$data = array(
'email'     => Input::get('email'),
'password'  => Input::get('password')
);

if (Auth::attempt($data)) {
    echo 'SUCCESS!';
}
```

This outputs SUCCESS, hence everything works. But if I next call another method the user is not logged in:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
echo "logged in";
}
else {
echo "not logged in";
}
```

This outputs 'not logged in'. I tried to add true to attempt to remember login but it does not make a diference. I have another Laravel App with Auth running that works perfectly.

Any ideas what the reason could be?

Comment: Ensure your session configuration is accurate, cookies are being saved to the correct domain, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Maybe this can help others:

After calling `Auth:attempt` you **must not** `echo` anything. You have do to a `redirect`. Does not make sense to me but solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

1.First Authenticate with :

```
     if (Auth::attempt($data)) {
  return Redirect::to('admin'); 
}
```

2.Then place this check to the page you have redirected your user after successful authentication 
In this case say 'admin' .

```
 if (Auth::check()) {
    echo "process";
    }
    else {
    return Redirect::to('login');
    }
```

Comment: This helped. But the reason is strange. I post as answere.

Comment: As far as I know you were successfully authenticated with `Auth::attempt($data)` , while `Auth::check()` checks the SESSION , where as the SESSION was not yet set as you placed the code just after the AUTH::attempt.. :) ? Got It . If you are satisfied with the answer plz mark it as checked .

Answer (score 0):

```
Event::listen('auth.login', function($user)
{
    echo 'user logged in'; 
});
```

Place this after `Auth::attempt($data)` and check.

Comment: Do you want to redirect the user to any specific page after successful login attempt or remain at the same page. ?

Comment: Redirect to anothe page. This is a login to a web app with many pages.

Comment: Then you should do it this way                                         if (Auth::attempt($data)) {
   return Redirect::to('admin');
}                                                                     // say admin or wherever you want to take the authenticated user