# Laravel 5.1 auth logs out after refresh

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication, laravel-5.1

I'm working with Laravel for the first time.
My auth user logs out automatically after i go to another route or if i refresh the page, and i dont understand why, please help me.

**This is my log in code:**

```
public function ini_ses(Request $datos)
{
    //Inicia sesion
    Session::put('ses_correo', Input::get('email'));

    $correo = $datos->input('email');
    $password= $datos->input('password');

    if(Auth::attempt(['correo_elec'=>$correo, 'password'=>$password]))
    {
        $_session['correo']=$correo;
        $_session['contra']=$password;

        if(Auth::user()->tipo==0)
        {
            return view('cliente');
        }
        elseif(Auth::user()->tipo==1)
        {
            return view('veterinario');
        }
        elseif(Auth::user()->tipo==2)
        {
            echo("Admin");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var_dump($correo, $password);
    }

}
```

If you know how to fix it, i aprecciate your help.

Comment: Are you using Laravel's authentication controllers or are you just using the classes manually? And what do your routes look like?

Comment: No, i'm using my own controllers and my login function is the one i posted.
And my routes are these:


Route::post('/inicio', 'Con_Usuario@ini_ses');
Route::post('/registro', 'Con_Usuario@reg');
Route::post('/RegMasc', 'Con_Mascota@reg');
Route::post('/RegVetria', 'Con_Vetria@reg');
Route::post('/Vinculacion', 'Con_Usuario@envio_cor');
Route::post('/mod_usu', 'Con_Usuario@mod');
Route::get('/mod_masc', 'Con_Mascota@mod');
Route::get('/cerrar', 'Con_Usuario@salir');
Route::get('mascota/{cod}', ['uses'=>'Con_Mascota@mod_masc']);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: Another possibility

[Laravel 4 Auth works but does not stay logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418755/laravel-4-auth-works-but-does-not-stay-logged-in)

Remove all, but the redirects. Apparently this may mess up the authentication process.

---

The Auth::attempt() should trigger the necessary things to keep the user logged in, a small yet simple possibility could be the remember me function. Although it shouldn't be that, it would be worth a try.

Add true as a second parameter to the function.

```
  if(Auth::attempt(['correo_elec'=>$correo, 'password'=>$password], true))
```

Assuming your Users table has the default laravel structure (with a remember token column)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which part? The removing all except redirects, or the remember me parameter?